# Can I close my Epic Games launcher while downloading GTA V?

Tags: epic-games-launcher

I'm installing GTA V right now, can I close the launcher and resume later? The launcher keeps asking me if I close all downloads will be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.** If you close the launcher, all downloads will be paused and you can continue from where you left off later.